# Get mailchimp form on one line with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, mailchimp

I am trying to get my mailchimp embed form all on one line, the call to signup, the input field and the submit button. I have tried following this answer here: https://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/JDrhG Tweaked a few things but still all in the middle and stacked on top of each other. http://theinvicto.com/

Tried changing the "clear: left" to "clear:none" and centered the form with text-align but still not on the same line. Would I use table for this?

HTML:

```css
   #mc_embed_signup{background:#50B1C5; clear:none; }
    
    #mc-embedded-subscribe-form.validate {
        background: #50B1C5;
    }
    
    
    #mc_embed_signup #mce-EMAIL {
        border: 3px solid #F3A733;
    }
    
    input#mc-embedded-subscribe.button {
    background-color: #F3A733;
    font-family: ‘Abel’;
    }
    
    *, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
     #mc_embed_signup{ clear:none; font:18px Abel,Arial,sans-serif; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}
     #mc_embed_signup form {display:block; position:relative; text-align:center;}
     #mc_embed_signup input {border:3px solid #F3A733; -webkit-appearance:none;}
     #mc_embed_signup input:focus {border-color:#333;}
     #mc_embed_signup .button {background-color: #F3A733; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:15px; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; margin: 0 5px 10px 0; padding:0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}
     #mc_embed_signup .button:hover {background-color:#EB7162;}
     #mc_embed_signup .small-meta {font-size: 11px;}
     #mc_embed_signup .nowrap {white-space:nowrap;}     
     #mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:none; display: inline-block; width: 31%; vertical-align: top;}
    
     #mc_embed_signup label {display:inline-block; font-size:16px; padding-bottom:10px; font-weight:bold; width: 70%;vertical-align: top;}
     #mc_embed_signup input.email {display:inline-block; padding:8px 0; margin:0 10px 10px 0; text-indent:5px; width:34%;vertical-align: top;}
     #mc_embed_signup input.button {display:block; width:100%; margin:0 0 10px 0;}
    
     @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
      #mc_embed_signup {width: 100%;}
      #mc_embed_signup label, #mc_embed_signup input.email, #mc_embed_signup .clear {display: block; width: 100%;}
     }
```

```html
 <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="https://theinvicto.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=197c4c27bd3b031b5957c0035&amp;id=0d6f057689" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
     <label for="mce-EMAIL"><span style="font-size: 35px;">be the first to know:</span></label>
     <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_197c4c27bd3b031b5957c0035_0d6f057689" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Let me know if anyone has had luck with something else. I'm learning and trying to troubleshoot but have finally decided to ask where I've gone wrong. Thinking maybe it's a display: table thing but I could be so wrong, hah.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a table for this. To put the button on the same line, you can simply use this:

```
.clear {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The `<div>` with the class "clear" displays as `block` by default, and since it contains the subscribe button, it will display on a new line. So changing it to `inline-block` will allow it to move to the same line.

However, looking at the source for your website, you've also got `<br>` and `<p>` tags between form elements, so those would have to be removed for this to work. Alternatively, you can just hide them using the following style:

```
#mc_embed_signup_scroll p,
#mc_embed_signup_scroll br {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This is getting me much closer. That sneaky <br> was somehow added by wordpress but I deleted it by putting my code all on the same line in the text editor in WP. I think I've gotten rid of that <p> tag now. The subscribe button is still on the bottom and the words are cut off now. do you know why?

Comment: @Emigriff It looks like there's still a `<p>` tag after the email input. Taking that out and adding the style in my answer seems to work fine.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a <p> tag I can't get rid of unless I do the website from scratch. It's something wordpress is adding in no matter what my code says in the cms :/ so I think I'm stuck with it

Comment: @Emigriff if it's something you can't get rid of, you can alternatively use `display: none` for those elements. I have updated my answer to include the styles.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! That's genius.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out centering this baby on mobile. Looks fine on my computer but is totally messed up on three different phones (no formatting, all to the left...) so close

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <p class="line">Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <input type="text" class="line">
  <button class="line">Submit</button>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.line {
  float: left;
}
```

Just put on each element float: left, if this doesnt work try to play with your width on the wrapper and each element, for ex: #wrapper="width: 100%" and since there are 3 elements just put each of them to have 33% width. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Ugh I tried playing around with this and no luck. Only just made the button text cut off https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPrgWV